# Do I need to add different sizes of the same drawables even though each of them has multiple DPI versions?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am using the "Icon Pack Drawable Importer" plugin which I think is probably importing the icons from "https://design.google.com/icons". Each icon has many sizes (18dp, 24, 36, 48...) and for each size, there are multiple DPIs (mdpi ~ xxxhdpi) for it.

This is a little bit confusing, because as far as I know on Windows, you just define multiple resolutions of the same icon, and the system will automatically choose the closest resolution (best) version for the actual drawing size.

Suppose I want to display two arrows in two different sizes on the same device. Suppose I only added one arrow icon whose size is 48dp but has 5 different DPI versions in it. If I specified the final drawable size programmatically, does Android select the closest one? For example, mdpi version for the small arrow and the xxxhdpi version for the large arrow? Or does Android select one version that matches the system's DPI and resize and use it for the two arrows?

I want to let users choose the icon size for them (some may want big, some may want small), but adding multiple size versions of one icon which itself has DPI versions seems a little bit complex. So, I thought of adding the biggest size only (48dp version, but it has 5 DPI versions in it) and specifying smaller resolution programmatically if the user wants smaller icon, because upscaling would make an icon blurry but downscaling would not. Is that a bad idea, and should I add multiple sizes and multiple DPIs of the same icon to the resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your screen is mdpi, all your drawables will be loaded first from res/drawable-mdpi directory, then, if the file is not found, from res/drawable directory. So if you resize 24x24 mdpi icon programmatically to 64x64 pixels, you will get degraded picture quality, Android will not load xxdpi icon for you instead.

If you set all your icon sizes in a programmatic way, simply select the highest-resolution icons and dump them all into res/drawable directory.

Icons in res/drawable-mdpi still has the advantage that they use less memory and don't need to be mipmapped, however modern phones can resize all graphics, with smoothing and mipmapping applied, in hardware.